# What is the significance of wearing dhoti during puja and other rituals?

Tags: puja

What is the significance of wearing dhoti during puja and other rituals ?

Comment: Old ways of doing things become ingrained in society as part of religious customs.

Comment: no particular dress code but traditional dresses gives good feel

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"It is mentioned in the Shastras that one should always wear a sacred/fresh (clean, washed and pure white) cloth while doing Puja everyday and 'Dhoti' is the purest forms of cloth. It is made to and can be be washed and easily dried up to wear every next day. Also the word itself means 'Dho' + 'Ti' a cloth that one can 'Dho'(a hindi/sanskrit word meaning wash) and wear a-fresh every day."

There are other reasons to believe by many others which are similar to that it is one of the simplest of clothes without any stitching and costly embroidery. Also there is a thinking that a proper Dhoti wearing does not involve any knot tied, hence simple wear.

Deriving one possible spiritual explanation out of this is that a type of cloth, i.e. dhoti, could be THAT simplest forms of cloth which is made to cover the body in the most simplest forms and which is its real purpose or to say which fulfills the ‘Need’ for what it is made mainly FOR and also there on, one can cross the fine line between the ‘Need’ and ‘Greed’ where the skillful designing, stitching and decoration like embroideries could take you away from the path of eternal bliss, which eventually has no end.

Source - https://www.vedicvaani.com/readymade-dhoti

Comment: Welcome to Hinduism.SE!  You should cite sources.